# Angular 2 component DOM binds to the property in component before it has bean resolved in OnInit method

Tags: javascript, angular

I am learning Angular 2 and trying to follow their tutorial.
Here is the code of the service that returns "Promise" of a mock object Folder.

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {FOLDER} from "./mock-folder";
import {Folder} from "./folder";
@Injectable()
export class FolderService {
  getFolder():Promise<Folder>{
    return Promise.resolve(FOLDER);
  }
}
```

It is declared in providers of my FolderModule

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {FolderComponent} from "./folder.component";
import {MaterialModule} from "@angular/material";
import {FolderService} from "./folder.service";
@NgModule({
  imports:[CommonModule, MaterialModule.forRoot()],
  exports:[FolderComponent],
  declarations:[FolderComponent],
  providers:[FolderService]
})
export class FolderModule{

}
```

Folder component should import FolderService and use it to obtain the Folder object.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Folder} from "./folder";
import {FolderService} from "./folder.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'folder',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: "./folder.component.html"
})
export class FolderComponent implements OnInit {
  folder:Folder;

  constructor(private folderService:FolderService) {
  }
  ngOnInit():void {
    this.getFolder();
  }
  getFolder() {
    this.folderService.getFolder().then((folder) => this.folder = folder);
  }
}
```

And yes, i do import my FolderModule in the root module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, CommonModule, MaterialModule.forRoot(), FolderModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers:[],
  declarations: [AppComponent, LifeMapComponent, MyPageNotFoundComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Here is the folder component template

```
<md-grid-list cols="3" [style.background] ="'lightblue'" gutterSize="5px">
  <md-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of folder.cards">{{card.title}}</md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

And here is the error i get in the console

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in
>   http://localhost:3000/app/folders/folder.component.html:1:16 caused
>   by: Cannot read property 'cards' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'cards' of undefined

```
export class Folder {
  public id:number;
  public title:string;
  public cards:Card[];
}

export class Card{
  id :number;
  title:string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voland,

This can be solved by using the "Elvis" operator on the collection being iterated over.

```
<md-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of folder.cards">{{card.title}}</md-grid-tile>
```

Should instead be:

```
<md-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of folder?.cards">{{card?.title}}</md-grid-tile>
```

Note the "?" after folder -- this will coerce the whole path to 'null', so it won't iterate.  The issue is with the accessor on a null object.

You could also declare folder to an empty array [] to prevent this.

EDIT:  To any onlookers, note that the Elvis operator is not available in your Typescript code, as it's not supported by the language.  I believe that Angular 2 supports it though, so it is available in your views (really useful for AJAX requests, where your data has not arrived at the point of component instantiation!)

Answer (score 1):

Use `*ngIf` directive:

```
<md-grid-list *ngIf="folder" cols="3" [style.background] ="'lightblue'" gutterSize="5px">
  <md-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of folder.cards">{{card.title}}</md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

Angular tries to render the html before the promise is resolved, therefore `folder` is `undefined` and the exception is thrown.
With `*ngIf="folder"` you tell Angular that it should ignore child elements if the expression is falsy.

`<md-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of folder.cards">{{card.title}}</md-grid-tile>` will be added to the DOM if `folder` is not `undefined`.

Comment: Yea thanks, i know, that it could be solved like this, but is there more elegant solution, in the tutorial it seems to be working without " if " statement.

Comment: I don't think there is a more "elegant" solution, check out the [official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngIf)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the classes:

```
export class Folder {
  public id:number;
  public title:string;
  public cards:Card[];
}

export class Card{
  id :number;
  title:string;
}
```

You have forgotten the constructor:

```
export class Folder {
  constructor( 
     public id:number,
     public title:string,
     public cards:Card[])
  {}
}

export class Card{
  constructor( 
    public id :number,
    public title:string)
  { }
}
```

And probably as previously suggested use the elvis operator or ngIf.

Comment: No, Folder is an object, but it has a property "cards" which is the array and i want to iterate through this array not Folder attributes.

Comment: ok, i think i should just stick with the Elvis operator, thanks :)